# Flutter, Dart, VSCode: set path to open GOOGLE chrome on a MAC (#30DaysOfFlutter)

Tags: flutter, google-chrome, dart, visual-studio-code

I'm running VSCode on a MAC. VSCode and also Google Chrome are installed on an external SSD drive with an Alias in the Program folder. Both programs are running absolutely fine and could also be started from the Alias in Launchpad. But if I press F5 for debugging Flutter/Dart then VSCode is trying to start Google Chrome via "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome" which is of course wrong. Is there a way to set the correct path to google chrome so VSCode is able to start it?

Answer (score 1):

If you run `flutter doctor -v` from a terminal, it should show where Flutter is finding Chrome and wants to launch it from:

```
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
```

If you set the `CHROME_EXECUTABLE` environment variable, this will override it:

```
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • CHROME_EXECUTABLE = /usr/bin/chromium
```

Note that the env variable needs to be set in a context that applies to VS Code (eg. setting it in a terminal startup script but then launching VS Code from outside of the terminal might not inherit the env variable). If you can't easily set it globally, you could add it to the `dart.env` setting in VS Code:

```
{
  "dart.env": {
    "CHROME_EXECUTABLE": "/foo"
  }
}
```